# Quantum Mechanics and Schur's lemma

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, mathematics, commutator

Today i was studying on a textbook and i crossed a paragraph that confused me a little.
Suppose you have an algebra generated by $\hat{X}$ and $\hat{P}$ and a function $f(\hat{X},\hat{P})$ that commutes with $\hat{X}$ and $\hat{P}$. Then you can prove that this function is proportional to the identity.
Here comes the issue, i don't understand the proof of this.
Reasoning in Position representation (meaning that $\hat{X}=x$ and $\hat{P}=-i\hbar\frac{d}{dx}$), i don't get why $[x,f]=0$ implies that $f=f(x)$ and why $[-i\hbar\frac{d}{dx},f]=0$ implies that $i\hbar\frac{df(x)}{dx}=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\psi(x)$ be any wave function, and *assume* $f$ can be formally expanded:$f=\sum_{km} a_{km} x^k p^m$. Then
\begin{align}
[x,f]\psi(x)&=x\left(\sum_{km} a_{km} x^k p^m\right)\psi(x)- \left(\sum_{km} a_{km} x^k p^m x\right)\psi(x)\, ,\\
&=\left(\left(\sum_{km} a_{km} x^{k} xp^m\right)- \left(\sum_k a_{km} x^k p^m x\right)\right)\psi(x)\, ,\\
&=\sum_{km}a_{km}x^k [x,p^m]\psi(x)\, .
\end{align}
If $[x,f]=0$, and since $[x,p^m]\ne 0$ unless $m=0$, it must hold that $a_{km}=0$ for $m\ne 0$, or 
$$
f=f(x)=\sum_{k}\tilde a_k x^k\, .
$$

Now consider $g(x,p)$
\begin{align}
[p,g(x,p)]\psi(x)&= p\left(\sum_{km} b_{km} x^k p^m\right) \psi(x) -\left(\sum_{km} b_{km} x^k p^m\right) p\psi(x)\, ,\\
&=\sum_{km} b_{km} [p,x^k] p^m\psi(x)\, .
\end{align}
Again, if you assume $[p,g]=0$ then the rhs is never $0$ unless $k=0$, implying this time that $g=g(p)$ only.

Comment: What if $f$ does not have the form of the assumption? Does the result still hold? If so, how does one prove it?

Comment: @Phoenix87  You are correct but a function of an operator is *usually* defined through its formal series expansion.  Admittedly this is a very low-tech answer that it avoids all kinds of technicalities, but it's simple enough.  Clearly the OP did not appreciate the language behind your (more formal) answer.  (I should clarify some additional minor points in my answer...)

Comment: So, in the end, it is not a proof of what the OP has asked. I think it is important to mention this, as this is usually the approach physicists take, i.e. trade in mathematical rigour for simplicity of the argument.

Comment: @Phoenix87 It's a valid proof given the assumptions stated clearly at the start.   As to the second part of your comment: I would rather observe that producing a complicated and overly technical answer to an elementary question is highfalutin by itself but can be very constructive as a complement to a simpler answer, especially if one can highlight the ways in which the simpler argument fails with a well chosen example.

Answer (score 2):

If $[x,f]=0$ then $f$ belongs to the commutant of $x$. Of course $x$ is in such a commutant, but $p$ isn't, therefore $f$ is a function of $x$ alone. Now, for any vector $\psi$ in the Hilbert space of the Schroedinger representation,
$$(f\psi)'(x) - (f\psi') = 0,\qquad\forall x$$
which implies that $(f'\psi)(x)=0$ for any $x$, hence $f'$ is the zero operator. Therefore $[p,f]=0$ implies $f'=0$, i.e. $f$ is a constant multiple of the identity operator.